# Using Luxon, how can I create a time-only object?

Tags: javascript, luxon

I am building an application which will store the opening hours for a business, e.g. `09:00` -> `17:00`

For ease of manipulation, I would like to create a Luxon object for the **time only**, without associating it with a particular date.

The reason for this is because the data type in the database is `time`.

I tried this:

```js
DateTime.fromObject({ hour: 9 }
```

...but ultimately it was associated with today's date:

```
2022-09-19T10:00:00.000+01:00
```

Comment: "*For ease of manipulation*" - what kind of manipulation do you need to do on those times?

Comment: Does [Duration](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#duration) suite your needs?

Comment: @Bergi I wanted to manipulate the timezone, but since you already answered that Luxon is not able to represent a date-independent time, I will research other avenues.

Comment: @Obvious_Grapefruit It doesn't really make sense to manipulate the timezone of a time-only value, since timezones behave differently depending on what date the timestamp is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luxon does not include a data structure to represent a date-independent time.